# How to use a for loop in the mongodb shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell, mongodb-aggregation

How can i use a for loop in the mongo db shell?

My attemps are stucking at this point:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i=i+0.12){
var n = i + 0.12;
db.test.aggregate(
    { $sort: {'deviation': -1}},
    { $unwind: '$foo' },
    { $match: { 'foo.km': {$gt: {n}, $lt: {i}}}},
    { $limit: 1}
)
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your loop condition is `false` on even the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: The condition is false, `i` need to be <= 6

Comment: Also, once the loop is fixed, I believe you want to swap the variables used for `$gt` and `$lt` as `n` is greater than `i`.

Comment: OK. i changed to <=6. But still, something is wrong

Comment: Also, please do not edit your original question like this when mistakes in your code are spotted. Most comments and answers are now completely out of context.

Comment: I want to aggregate from 0 to 6 in steps of 0.12. 
there are apparently a  in line 6 "}" wrong but i have no what...

Answer (score 6):

MongoDB shell uses javascript engine and I remember in javascript some year ago some problem with using var keyword inside loop as we use int inside java.

try by removing var from loop statement

```
for (i = 0; i <= 6; i=i+0.12){ 
  var n = i + 0.12;
 db.test.aggregate([
  { $sort: {'deviation': -1}},
  { $unwind: '$foo' },
  { $match: { 'foo.km': {$gt: {n}, $lt: {i}}}},
  { $limit: 1}
 ])
}
```

Also be mindful that js is asynchronous by default, so it might not wait for aggregate to complete and might move to next iteration.

Comment: still have this Error:
Error: Line 6: Unexpected token }

Comment: On a second look seems like aggregate argument should be inside array, I updated the answer.

Comment: Rahul Kumar, please elaborate on what do you mean by JS being asynchronous by default. I highly doubt that.

Comment: What I meant in simple term is that In JS it won’t wait for any I/O call to be completed and would jump on the next line of execution, that’s why we have callbacks in js.

Answer (score 5):

Insert many item at once.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
   db.collectionName.insert({ x : i })
}
```

To check

```
db.collectionName.find();
```

Answer (score 2):

The code works like this but there are no results to show. At least not a syntax error anymmore

```
for (i = 0; i <= 6; i=i+0.12){ 
  var n = i + 0.12;
 db.test.aggregate(
  { $sort: {'deviation': -1}},
  { $unwind: '$foo' },
  { $match: { 'foo.km': {$gt: [n], $lt: [i]}}},
  { $limit: 1}
 )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I stuck on same error in past. We should use spaces/tabs in loop for every line with perfect coding style.

2nd thing is here n is greater than i. Then match query should like foo.km < n and foo.km > i

So, this is final code -

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i=i+0.12){
    var n = i + 0.12;
    db.test.aggregate(
        { $sort: {'deviation': -1}},
        { $unwind: '$foo' },
        { $match: { 'foo.km': {$lt: {n}, $gt: {i}}}},
        { $limit: 1}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is wrong, It should be <=6. Like this

```
for (i = 0; i <= 6; i=i+0.12){
 //your logic
}
```